# Finding Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager library for C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I am using `System.Management.Automation` namespace in order to use powershell within C# .NET program.

However according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx `Add-WindowsFeature` returns `Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationResult` type.

This object is undocumented on MSDN but I was able to retrieve it's members using PowerShell and `Get-Member` command.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $RES[0] | Get-Member


   TypeName: Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationResult

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
Equals        Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode   Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method     type GetType()
ToString      Method     string ToString()
ExitCode      Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationExitCode ExitCode {get;}
FeatureResult Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureResult[] FeatureResult {get;}
RestartNeeded Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.RestartState RestartNeeded {get;}
Success       Property   System.Boolean Success {get;}
```

Now I'd like to use this type in C# but for this I need to have library that has this namespace. I could only find

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.servermanager_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_c70b231167ed6fc3
```

directory where `Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.dll` was located. This library can be referenced in visual studio but it's namespace does not contain `.Commands` namespace(?)class(?)

1. Any idea where I can find it proper library?
2. Perhaps there is way to retrieve Success (boolean) property without adding this library as a reference?

in C# `$RES` would have [`PSObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject(v=vs.85).aspx) type as it's result of [`Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke(v=vs.85).aspx) command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. In order to be able to use `Add-WindowsFeature` you have to import server module called `ServerManager` first. This server module is located in

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ServerManager
```

directory. In the same directory there is `ServerManager.psd1` file that contains line

```
NestedModules = 'Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.PowerShell'
```

If you search for `Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.PowerShell.dll` library. You should find an instance of it and this instance contains the `.Commands` namespace I mentioned in the question.

Comment: As of Windows 10, that assembly is in the GAC. You can inspect the types with ILSpy.

Answer (score 0):

The name and location of the relevant DLL is an implementation detail, and may change from release to release. I've found that the easiest way to deal with structured objects in PowerShell results is to use the C# 'dynamic' feature. For example:

```
public bool FeatureIsInstalled(string name)
{
    bool result = false;

    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(
        string.Format("Get-WindowsFeature '{0}'", name)))
    {
        Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
        if (output.Count > 0)
        {
            dynamic o1 = output[0];
            result = (bool)o1.Installed;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```